# How to divide first number in a pandas series with the sum of all the numbers in a series in Python

Tags: python, pandas, series

I have a pandas series which looks like this..

```
dish_name
Chiken Biryani    3
Mutton Biryani    1
Paneer Biryani    4
Paneer Pulav      2
sandwitch         2
```

I want to calculate 1st dish divide by rest of the dishes quantity..so it should be like.. first element (3/(3+1+4+2+2) then second element (1/(3+1+4+2+2) and so on till the last element.. 
Here is what I am doing

```
def dish_push(dish_data):
dish_number = len(dish_data)
for i in range(0,dish_number):
    dish = (dish_data[i])/(dish_data[0:dish_number].sum())
    print dish
```

But its not giving me desired results.. What I want is

```
dish_name
Chiken Biryani    0.25
Mutton Biryani    0.083
Paneer Biryani    0.33
Paneer Pulav      0.16
sandwitch         0.16
```

Is there something wrong with my logic? please help

Comment: What is the output that you're getting?

Comment: I got the desired output.. changed my code.. But i got only values,,How to add corresponding dish name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
print(s/s.sum())

Chiken Biryani    0.250000 
Mutton Biryani    0.083333
Paneer Biryani    0.333333
Paneer Pulav      0.166667
sandwitch         0.166667
dtype: float64
```

Comment: yes.. this is what I want.. And I got the logic..But the thing is its returning only values `0.25 0.083 0,33 0.16 0.16`  I want corresponding dish name to be printed as well.

Comment: You mean when you use print(s/s.sum()) you don't get the series index labels? Check the construction of your pandas Series object. Either do print(s) and you should see the dish name before the amount or do print(s.index) and you should get a list of the dishes. If you don't get anything or get an error with s.index then you don't have a pandas Series object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use python dict to achive this as below,

```
def dish_push(dish_data):
    dish_number = len(dish_data)
    total=0
    for key in dish_data:
        total+=dish_data[key]
    for key in dish_data:
        dish_val = (float(dish_data[key])/float(total))
        print key + " " + str(dish_val)

dish_data={"chicken Briyani":3,
            "Mutton Biryani":1,
            "Paneer Briyani":4,
            "Paneer Pulav":2,
            "sandwitch":2
          }
#main
dish_push(dish_data)
```

===================================

```
Paneer Briyani           0.333333333333
chicken Briyani           0.25
Mutton Biryani           0.0833333333333
sandwitch           0.166666666667
Paneer Pulav           0.166666666667
```

Here I am looping 2 times, 1st time to get count this code can still be simplified by using list comprehension i guess.